# difference in single quote and double quote while doing comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var str = ' some value, 1, 2 , test3'; 
   str +="test string, 12, test12";   
   var varArray = new Array();
   varArray = str .split(",");
   if(varArray[i] == '' || varArray[i] == "")
   {
    //some logic
    }
```

I have referred this piece of code from some blogs.
I am curious, is there any difference in both comparison in if condition .
is it specific to browser.
Please help me to know the reason of using this. or both are same.

Comment: there is no difference... where did you see them....

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious, is there any difference in both comparison in if condition

No. JavaScript just lets you use either kind of quotes around a string literal in your code. The **only** difference is that inside a string literal quoted with `"`, you have to escape the `"` character, but not the `'` character; inside a string literal quoted with `'`, you have to escape `'` but not `"`. There is **no difference at all** in the resulting string, it's purely about how you write the literal in the code.

Examples:

```
var s1 = "I'm a string";  // Doesn't need \ before '
var s2 = 'I\'m a string'; // Does need \ before '
console.log(s1 === s2);   // true, they're the same string

var s3 = 'He said "Hello," smiling';   // Doesn't need \ before "
var s4 = "He said \"Hello,\" smiling"; // Does need \ before "
console.log(s3 === s4);                // true, they're the same string
```

So regarding the `if`:

```
if(varArray[i] == '' || varArray[i] == "")
```

The second half of that is completely unnecessary.

> is it specific to browser.

No.

Comment: Thanks . point you mentioned , I am aware of escaping ' & ".
finally no difference.